# Bypass Itunes Connect Testflight app-beta review

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect, testflight

I'm working with apple itunes connect website.
I want that my friend with an iphone can install my app from testflight. 
My friend isn't part of my work team so he isn't listed in itunes connect users and cannot be an internal tester.

The "standard process" will be:

- send app-beta review request.
- wait for the review result
- once is approved send invitation to external tester

I need that my friend will be able to run my app without waiting for beta-review (review request are disabled on holidays).

So i do the following:

- add my friend to itunes connect users and give him developer privileges (he will have these privileges for a short time - and will not even know he has them).
- he has to read the email received and click the link to activate itunes account.
- add him to testflight internal tester so he can install my app.
- finally my friend install my app from testflight
- then, i remove my friend from both internal tester and itunes connect users so he has my app installed without wait the app review.

Will my app remain installed even if he is removed by internal testers and also by itunes connect users?

If yes this is a good method to skip the "so frustrating" apple app beta review process.

Comment: Just give him an adhoc build to self-sign if you absolutely don't want to go through the TestFlight review process (which takes way less time than an ordinary review and they are more lenient, and its automatic for subsequent builds for the same version of the app).

Comment: "Will my app remain installed even if he is removed by internal testers and also by itunes connect users?"  that's a good question!  I don't know!

Answer (score 9):

Actually, there is a way to skip review process. When you upload new build you just change *Build*, and **not Version**. You pass review for particular *Version* and then stack your *Build*'s under this version without review (still, when you submit, button *Submit to review* is active but you will pass instantly). Enjoy.

Comment: is this still valid in 2020?

Comment: @rajeshzmoke No

Answer (score 1):

If the AppStore were open, I would say to just wait for review.  Each additional review for betas of the same version are automatic.

But, since that is not the case, you can do as you describe and it will work.

Another way is to get the UDID of the user, add it to your developer.apple.com account, make AdHoc profiles and make an AdHoc build.  Then use something like Hockey to get them the build.

Comment: AdHoc build + Hockey is nice!